# python find min value in the list of dictionary plus if condition

Tags: python, lambda, conditional-statements

I have the following list of dictionaries,

```
aa=[{'score': 1.463179736705023, 'type': 'exam'}, 
    {'score': 6.676176060654615, 'type': 'homework'}, 
    {'score': 11.78273309957772, 'type': 'quiz'}, 
    {'score': 35.8740349954354, 'type': 'homework'}]

>>> obj=min(aa,key=lambda y:y['score'])
>>> print obj
{'score': 1.463179736705023, 'type': 'exam'}
```

tried this:

```
>>> obj1=min(aa,key=lambda y:y['score',{'type':"homework"}])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
    TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Now how to find the object with min scores only if type="homework" ?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> aa=[{'score': 1.463179736705023, 'type': 'exam'}, {'score': 6.676176060654615, 'type': 'homework'}, {'score': 11.78273309957772, 'type': 'quiz'}, {'score': 35.8740349954354, 'type': 'homework'}]
>>> min((x for x in aa if x["type"] == "homework"), key=lambda y:y['score'])
{'score': 6.676176060654615, 'type': 'homework'}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the low score:

```
min(d['score'] for d in aa if d['type'] == 'homework')
```

If you want the whole object, not just the low score:

```
low = min(d['score'] for d in aa if d['type'] == 'homework')
[d for d in a if d == {'score':low, 'type':'homework'}]
```

This returns a list of all the objects with the lowest score (in case people tied for lowest).

Comment: I think replacing the lambda is better here: +1

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
>>> min((x for x in aa if x["type"] == "homework"), key=lambda x:x['score'])
{'score': 6.676176060654615, 'type': 'homework'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter by 'type' and get min by key 'score':

```
>>> min(filter(lambda x: x['type'] == 'homework', aa), key=lambda x: x['score'])
{'score': 6.676176060654615, 'type': 'homework'}
```